# How to join data aggregated by day on main table

Tags: join, count, aggregate-functions

I would like to be able to join data aggregated by day on a non-aggregated table.

Fields: id, date

Table: case

```
date  id
1/1   31   
1/1   22   
1/1   36   
1/1   44   
1/2   51   
1/2   64
```

My end result should be:

```
date  id  total_id_per_day
1/1   31   4
1/1   22   4
1/1   36   4
1/1   44   4
1/2   51   2
1/2   64   2
```

I've tried the following, which is not working as intended:

```
with idtotal as (select date, count(distinct id) as total_id_per_day from case group by date)

select c.date, c.id, idtotal.total_id_per_day
from case as c
left join idtotal on idtotal.date = case.date
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you version of SQL support analytic functions, then use `COUNT` here:

```sql
SELECT date, id, COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY date) total_id_per_day
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```

If you are stuck without analytic functions, then use a join to a subquery which finds the counts:

```sql
SELECT t1.date, t1.id, t2.cnt AS total_id_per_day
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, COUNT(id) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY date
) t2
    ON t2.date = t1.date
ORDER BY
    t1.date;
```

Comment: Thank you! The first option is exactly what I needed!